# How to append a 3D array inside a parfor in matlab?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, append, parfor

I have several gray-scale images and I want to store that in a 3d array(hieghtXwidthXnumber-of-images) in matlab.

my code looks like this

```
train_img = [];
parfor i=1:100
      a = imread(image-file);
      a1 = imresize(a, 0.5);
      b = rgb2gray(a1);
      d = im2double(b);
      train_label = [train_label;p];
      train_img = cat(3,train_img(:,:,:),d);
end
```

> Error: The temporary variable train_img in a parfor is uninitialized.
>   See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Uninitialized Temporaries".

In the above code the parfor i=1:**100**, I don't know whats the upper limit of loop. Its decided at run time.
Could anybody let me know what this error means and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You write `train_img` on the left as well as the right hand side of an expression. Therefore, next iteration depends on the previous value of `train_img`. This prevents MATALB from employing `parfor`. If you modify the code as follows, it should work:

```
parfor i=1:your_upper_bound %it can be a variable too, just define it
      a = imread(image_file);
      a1 = imresize(a, 0.5);
      b = rgb2gray(a1);
      d = im2double(b);
      train_label(i,1) = p; % if this doesn't work -> define train_label before parfor
      train_img(:,:,i) = d; % if this doesn't work -> define train_img before parfor
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it possible to append 2d arrays to train_img(3d array) in third dimension without using index? like I want to replace train_img(:,:,i) = d which uses i , to train_label = [train_label;p]. Is it possible?

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi I think the whole point of the answer is that you specifically can't have `train_label` on the left and right, so no

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi It is not possible when using parfor but I don't see why you need that. Could you tell me a scenario where you think you need it?